# Google Maps JavaScript - adding multiple markers to one map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having difficulty setting event handlers to Google Maps markers in JavaScript. Below is my code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                zoom: 8,
                center: {lat: -35, lng: 149}
            });
            for (var i = 0; i < basketballCourts.length; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(basketballCourts[i].latitude, basketballCourts[i].longitude),
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });
                marker.set("data-index", i);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    console.log(marker.get("data-index"));
                });
            }
```

You'll notice that there is a click event for the markers. However, the click event is the same for **all the markers**. A different number should be logged for every marker click, but no matter what marker I click on, I get the same response.

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Try `this.get("data-index")` to see if you can use this to get the correct marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is you're looping over all your basketballCourts, creating an event listener for each marker.  That's all well and good.  However that event listener function looks like:

`console.log(marker.get("data-index"));`

The function executes in response to a marker click, not when you define it.  And the value of `marker` when the function executes will be the value it had at the end of your loop over all the basketballCourts.

Using @MiltoxBeyond's suggestion, try using `this.get("data-index")`